# MySQL phpMyAdmin unclosed quote error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using the below SQL code for MySQL to input from a csv file, and I am getting the following error message in phpMyAdmin. I tried escape characters, I tried writing the code in a php file with a try/catch but nothing is thrown. I've search for a long time to get past this and the only thing that may be the problem is phpMyAdmin needs updated, but the php code didn't work and I don't have access to update phpMyAdmin ... it is on Yahoo/Aabaco web hosting. I reviewed the other questions on this topic and they had an obvious missing quote or error. I tried '\r\n' and '/r/n' as per a topic suggested to me here. I'll keep trying anything and everything. Thanks! I tried changing FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' to '-' just to see if it got past that error and it didn't. I removed the line and received the error on the next line.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.CSV'
INTO TABLE
ip2location_db9
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

phpMyAdmin Error Message:

[image: phpMyAdmin Error Message]

Comment: It is not a duplicate. It would be if I was asking where my syntax error was. But, there is no error. The problem is Yahoo/Aabaco web hosting. I even tried a simple SELECT for duplicates and it failed. I am dropping them and getting a new hosting service. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Don't post PICTURES of errors/code. They're useless. What you posted above as text is **NOT** what's in your error image:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'
```

Why is all that stuff escaped? Your "unterminated" quote is a problem at the PHPMyAdmin level, caused by the unecessary extra escaping on done on the raw query.

Comment: I didn't add the escapes, MyPHPAdmin added those.